# SED delete csv column if exists

Tags: sed, csv, delete

I need to remove a column from my tabulated CSV file if this column exists.

My CSV file:

```
GENE REF ALT
AKT  A   G
AKT  G   G
```

Desired output:
if column REF exists delete this column

```
GENE  ALT
AKT    G
AKT    G
```

I tried to do that:

```
sed 's/\tREF.[^\t]*//' filename.csv
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use awk: `awk 'NF == 3 { print $1,$3}` file`

Comment: Hi Valentin, thanks for your reply. The thing is sometimes REF column can exists sometimes not. Is with your command line it will remove always column 2?

Comment: No. The `NF` checks if there are at least 3 fields. You might also want `awk -vOFS="\t" 'NF.....} file`.

Comment: what about `awk '{ print $1, $NF}' OFS='\t' infile`?

Comment: sed is not the right tool for this job. The word REF does not appear on *every* line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi with miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) and this input.csv

```
GENE,REF,ALT
AKT,A,G
AKT,G,G
```

is very easy

```
mlr --csv cut -x -f REF input.csv
```

The output is

```
GENE,ALT
AKT,G
AKT,G
```

Comment: This miller tool works good :-)

Answer (score 5):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane '@non_ref_cols = grep { $F[$_] ne "REF" } 0..$#F if $. == 1;
                     print join "\t", @F[@non_ref_cols]' ip.txt
GENE    ALT
AKT     G
AKT     G
```

- `-F'\t'` use tab as field separator
- `@non_ref_cols = grep { $F[$_] ne "REF" } 0..$#F if $. == 1` for the header line, get index of all fields that is NOT `REF`
- `print join "\t", @F[@non_ref_cols]` print all fields using the index array we got for the header line, using tab as field separator

Comment: Nice solution. I improved your variable name for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could determine which column `REF` is at with `grep` and then decide to delete it, e.g. with GNU cut and assuming your headings are single words and delimiters are tabs:

```
colnumber=$(head -n1 file.tsv | grep -o '[^\t]\+' | grep -nx 'REF' | cut -d: -f1)
[[ -n $colnumber ]] && cut --complement -f$colnumber file.tsv > file.tsv.new
```

Output:

```
GENE    ALT
AKT     G
AKT     G
```

Comment: Very nice. Great idea to use --complement. You might want to add `-d $'\t'` to the cut command. I would use `grep -nx REF`, but given the previous grep, that's no different.

Comment: After a 2nd look, this would be safer given it's a tab-separated file and spaces would be allowed as valid field characters: `grep -Eo [^\t]+ | grep -nx REF`

Comment: @glennjackman: I agree, updated.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
  NR == 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "REF") refCol = i}
  refCol {for (i = refCol + 1; i <=NF; i++) $(i-1) = $i; NF--}
  1
' file.csv
```

The first line finds which column is the REF column. The refCol variable will be uninitialized if there is no such column.
The second line removes the column if it has been found.
The third line prints the record.